# Require 2 properties if one is present unless they are nested under a specific property

Tags: node.js, joi

I have this joi schema which requires that if you pass in `id`, you must also pass in `type`.

```
joi
    .object()
    .required()
    .keys({
        id: joi.string(),
        type: joi.string(),

        expirationTime: dateSchema,
        createdBy: joi.string().uuid(),
        createdAt: dateSchema,

        // Allow "or" to recursively reference this entire schema.
        // https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#linkref
        or: joi.array().items(joi.link('/')).min(2),

        // Allow "and" to recursively reference this entire schema.
        // https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#linkref
        and: joi.array().items(joi.link('/')).min(2)
    });
    .with('id', 'type'); // If searching for id you must also search by type
```

I want to make it so that if you pass in `id`, you must also pass in `type`, unless it is nested under `and`.

For example this should fail because it does not have `id` AND `type`

```
{
  id: 'foo',
}
```

But this should pass because it does have `id` AND `type` at the root level AND only `id` when nested under `and`.

```
{
  id: 'foo',
  type: 'bar',
  and: [{ id: 'foobar' }, { createdBy: 'me' }]
}
```

Comment: The or/and "children" look like a different schema then, with some shared components.   Are they meant to support or/and recursively?

Comment: Yes it is meant to support and/or recursively. The only difference is when nested under `and` or `or`, `id` does not also require `type`.

Answer (score 0):

The `or`/`and` "children" are a different schema.

You could define a `base` schema for the common elements

```
const base = Joi.object()
    .keys({
        id: Joi.string(),
        type: Joi.string(),
        expirationTime: dateSchema,
        createdBy: Joi.string().uuid(),
        createdAt: dateSchema,
        or: Joi.array().items(Joi.link('#base')).min(2),
        and: Joi.array().items(Joi.link('#base')).min(2),
    })
    .id('base')
```

Then create the "head" schema with the additions, and allowing it to still reference `#base`

```
const head = base
    .keys({
         id: Joi.string()
    })
    .required()
    .with('id', 'type')
    .id('head')
    .shared(base)
```

The `.keys()` extension is a bit clunky as `null/undefined/{}` have special meaning in Joi to change validation behaviour, so I had to pick a key to redefine to make it "extend".